# Powershell stored procedure string containing xml passes to sp as xml instead of string

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a PowerShell module project where I have to call a stored procedure in SQL Server. One of the parameters is expecting a `NVarChar`. The string is xml as a string (i.e. $x = "`<Objects><object></object></Objects>`"

I have tried:

```
[string]$x = "`<Objects><object></object></Objects>`"
```

and

```
$x = "`<Objects><object></object></Objects>`"

$x = $x.ToString()
```

as part of the stored procedure call this is what I have:

```
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.Connection = OpenSqlConnection "databaseName"

$sqlCmd.CommandText = "dbo.sp_Call"
$sqlCmd.CommandType=[System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'

$sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Object",[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar);
$sqlCmd.Parameters["@Object"].Value = $ObjectXML;


$RowsEffected = $sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I've also tried

```
$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Object", $ObjectXML)
```

and

```
$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Object", [string]$ObjectXML)
```

No matter what I do I always get an error:

> Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you set `$ObjectXML` to an empty string? Is the procedure called correctly then?

Comment: Would be nice to have the declare parameter section of your stored proc as well.

Comment: Show us your SQL procedure. Message suggests problem is there.

Comment: `@ContractID INT  = NULL,
 @CampaignStartDate Datetime ,
 @CreatedBy uniqueidentifier = null,
 @Mode varchar(10) = NULL,
 @Description varchar(100) =  NULL,
 @Type  varchar(50) =  NULL,
 @Name varchar(100)= NULL ,
 @Status varchar(20) =  NULL, 
 @Retries int = NULL,
 @RetryInterval int = null,
 @PolupationList VARCHAR(max) = null,
 @TemplateList VARCHAR(max) = null,
 @CampaignObject  NVARCHAR(max) = null,
 @UpdatedBy UniqueIdentifier = Null,
 @CampaignID INT = NULL,
 @EndDate Datetime = NULL` 


This is the variables expected by the stored procedure

Comment: So I've tested and it seems to be a problem with SQL. I tried running the stored procedure from SSMS and with just @Object='`<Objects><object></object></Objects>`'

And I get the same error. It seems that even though it's past as a string, sql sees the xml structure and tries to do an implicit conversion. I'll post if I find a solution.